# Conditional Formatting when condition is met on two columns

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting

Within Power BI I have two columns, one that contains Yes or No and the other a Date Column.

What I am looking for is for when the answer in Column 1 is No and is older than two days then highlight as Red (similar to what can be done in excel)

I have tried a couple of measures, but they just appear to return as 0.

Is there a way to either highlight no's in red if condition is met, or to show the number of No's where answer is no if older than 2 days?

[image: Example]

Comment: Please share some data and sample mockup.

Comment: I've now edited the post sharing an example of what I am looking to replicate in Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue with the following formula.

```
Conditional Formatting = IF(SELECTEDVALUE
('TableName'[Flag]) = "NO" && SELECTEDVALUE
('TableName'[Evaluation Date])<=TODAY()-2,1,0)
```